# Date and time data type in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timestamp

I want to store timestamps in my SQLite database and [this answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401415/1416629) was looking promising. Then, I saw the SQLite documentation which says that there are only 4 data types: `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, `BLOB`. How do I go about? Also, millisecond precision would be useful though I can manage if it only gives precision upto a second. Also, timezone isn't important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Milliseconds or seconds since an epoch in an `INTEGER`. sqlite `INTEGER`s support up to 64 bits of storage.

Convert to/from string representations with timezone support in code.

Comment: I would say use the milliseconds since most languages deal with milliseconds relative to UTC, so it would be even easier to work with timezones: store millis in UTC in DB then interpret based on timezone on client device.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not have a separate storage class for storing dates and/or times, but SQLite is capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL or INTEGER values.

1) TEXT - A date in a format like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS".

2) REAL - The number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C.

3) INTEGER - The number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

For more details you can visit [TutorialsPoint SQLite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm)